# Search across multiple lines: selection

Tags: search, vim, pattern-matching, lines

text example:

```
<div> test </div>
test test test 
test <div> test
test test test
test </div> test
test test test
```

I want to select from `<div>` to `</div>`.

My search:

```
<div>\_.\{-}</div>
```

However..
1) it does not select `<div> test </div>` on the 1st line.
2) it does select from `<div>` on the 3rd line but not to the `<div>` on the 5th line but to the end of the 5th line.

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in vim try this:

```
/<div>\_.\{-}<\/div>
```

you should escape the last `/`, so that let vim know that it belongs to the pattern.

it is `/pattern/{offset}<cr>` without the escaping, vim thinks the following chars are offsets.

### Update

It works as you expected here. Using relative simple vim config:

https://github.com/sk1418/myConf/blob/master/common/base.vimrc

In the below screenshot, the command line output is from `:echo @/` As you see, the highlighted text are exactly what you want.

[image]

Comment: Hello Kent, yes you're that resolves my 1st problem not the 2nd. It still selects the entire 5th line. I tried to change `<div>` on the 3rd line in `abc` and the `<\div>` on the 5th line in `edf`, it still selects from line 3 till line 5 (entire line), if I search `abc\_.\{-}def`

Comment: I used your base.vimrc file (_vimrc), it still selects the entire 5th line. It must be my vim version I suppose. Plugins are not loaded in your vimrc. I use the 64bit harogan build of vim (lua enabled).

Comment: It was my vim version. I uninstalled my 64 bit version, downloaded the latest vim (gvim-7-4-827.exe), installed it and now it works fine. Thank you very much Kent.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use `vat`

See answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/450766/vim-how-to-select-a-whole-html-block-including-the-tags), or `:help at`

Comment: OP wants to select multiple tags not single `<div>` but all `<div>s`

Comment: You're right @Kent, I was missing the fact that it should be multiple selection (hlsearch). I'll still leave my answer because in this context you may want to search for `<div>` only, then `vat` to select a tag block, which has the advantage of working with nested blocks.